# How can I find a memory leak in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

My current model seems to have a memory leak. The task manager (on Windows 10) shows the amount of memory used slowly creeping upwards.  I have a fixed number of agents (about 70) and no links. I can't think of any place where a list grows without bounds. I do a lot of replacements in lists, using them like arrays. Might that cause a leak? Perhaps I should try arrays.

Other possible leaks. I use an output area rather than the View to follow the model. But at each `go` cycle I `clear-output`. I also use tables, but with a fixed set of keys and with fixed sized values.

Any thought about how/where I should look for the leak? Eventually -- and not very quickly -- I get a message saying that I've run out of memory.

Thanks.

Comment: would the model still run if you commented out some of the list replacements? If so, you could try and isolate the problem generator.

Comment: I apologize, but today when I ran it, there was no memory leak. Don't understand why. But ti no longer seems to be a problem. Apologies.

Comment: We don't have special tools for this in NetLogo. You'd probably have to fall back on a non-NetLogo-specific tool such as a JVM heap analyzer.

Comment: No problem. I've started the clean up, but you could delete this post yourself since it doesn't have any answers